# database column check PK and overwrite another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server 2008 database, the code (now corrected) has accidently overwrite one column with wrong data about 50,000 rows
The rows might have changed since the backup, but the primary key is intact now I have two database one with correct data in one column and one with incorrect data.

Can anyone help with a script to recover this columns data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `update` statement to copy data from the restored database:

```
update  wrong
set     WrongColumn = [right].WrongColumn
from    ProductionDb.dbo.Table1 as wrong
join    RestoredDb.dbo.Table1 as [right]
on      [right].PrimaryKeyCol = wrong.PrimaryKeyCol
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tablediff that will generate a script for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx